# Change In-app Subscription amount From GBP to USD

Tags: android, in-app, google-play-console, in-app-subscription

I am creating a new subscription in in-app product in Google play console. When I tried to add price, it populated a form to enter amount in GBP. I want to enter the subscription amount in USD.

I understand this is because of my merchant profile address is in UK.

Is there any way to enter subscription amount in USD?

Or someone please tell me which address deciding my app's local currency in play console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default price for your subscription will be in the default currency for your merchant account. However, once you create the subscription [you can set different prices in different countries](https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/earn/subscriptions), eg a USD price for US users.

Comment: Thanks Nick. So, I can only enter default subscription amount in USD only if my merchant account is in US. Right?

Comment: Is there any other way to enter default value in USD?

Answer (score -1):

Please note that depending on what Google service you use to make a purchase, the currency you're billed in may not be the currency of your home country. If possible, Google will charge you in the currency of your home country.
Google gets this information from the home address that you added.

Try changing your current country of residence by following the below instructions:

Sign into your Google Payments account at payments.google.com and click the Settings icon in the top corner.

Click Edit next to the "Home Address" listed and update the address (please note this is different from the "Address Book" which holds shipping addresses).

Open the Play Store and navigate to any item available for download.

Click to begin a download until you reach the "Accept and buy" screen (no need to complete the purchase)

Close the Play Store, force stop and then clear data for the Google Play Store application (Settings > Apps > Google Play Store > Force Stop then Clear Data) or clear your browser cache

Re-open the Play Store.

You should now see the Play Store that matches your default payment method’s billing country.

If you still aren't able to change your home country, please note that while changing home address is possible under specific circumstances, there are some limitations. You can't change your home address country if you:

Recently changed your country.
Have a billable service that isn't supported in the new country.

Become "locked" for financial industry reasons and can't be changed.
If you have a Google Payments Merchant account or Google Play balance/Google Wallet balance higher than $10, or the equivalent in your country's currency, you won't be able to change your home country.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this isn't related to my question.